# What is the fastest way to search all the files in hard disk?

Tags: c++, c, windows, visual-c++

I am currently trying to search all the files in the hard disk.

I'll search a lot of documents on window 7. That means using lot of File I/O...

I am thinking I should use multi-thread or Asynchronous I/O.

What do you think?

Comment: Depends entirely on what kind of search you are going to do. What are you searching for?  Generally speaking, the CPU is going to be faster than the I/O, so one thread is enough, but it depends on _how_ you are searching and what _for_.

Comment: The important thing is to avoid thrashing (seeking back and forth) if you have a disk with poor random access performance.  Generally one thread per physical disk (not partition!) is ideal.

Comment: One *reading* thread per disk - you could have a second thread doing the actual searching.

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant I'm searching keywords on every documents. I'll search every file. Starting on C:\ as root.

Comment: What wrong with [find](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/find.mspx)? eg, not tested: `find /i "curriculum" C:\*.*`

Comment: @pmg it's actually not that simple....

Comment: If you are only interested in documents, then user the document indexing service.

Comment: I'll search only once so indexing service is not good I think...

Comment: @YoungHyunYoo: If the indexing service has _already_ indexed everything, your search can use those results. If not, using it will be just as fast as anything you can invent. Both will be limited by disk I/O.

Comment: @Young Hyun Yoo: If you are reading each document to look for keywords you will need multiple programs to do that depending on the kind of documents they are: DOCX or PDFX or PostScript etc. You could use a thread to run each of these programs.

Answer (score 0):

If you think about it the right way, this can lend itself well to a worker pipeline: thread 1 consumes a list of directories to retrieve and fetches directory listings. Thread 2 consumes directory listings and dispatches additional directories back to thread 1 while forwarding files to thread 3.

Thread 3 meanwhile has a simple job: fetch N pages of data at a time from files and forward them to thread 4 which searches pages of memory for matches.

Because the application is largely going to be IO bound, you can comfortably afford to invest some CPU in thread 3 to optimize the concurrency and priority of requests to try and ensure that you maximize the speed with which new pages are delivered to thread 4 and thus how quickly the entire process completes.

OTOH, you may find that just switching to [memory-mapped IO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810613.aspx) will produce a less complex solution with a good-enough speed.